# Passing output of a linux command to another

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I am trying to pass the output of a linux command to another command as an argument in Android debugging.

Here is the steps I want to combine .

1. Finding out the binary path using `adb shell pm path com.test.example`

   The output being : `package:/data/app/test.apk`
2. Strip first 9 characters from the output using `cut -c 9-`

   The output being `/data/app/test.apk`
3. Use the output of 2nd in my 3rd command `adb pull`

I tried doing something like :

`adb shell pm path com.test.example | cut -c 9- | adb pull -`

But this doesn't work. Can someone suggest why and what would be the correct solution or a better approach?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass output of one command to another command as arguments by using `xargs`.

```
echo "Name" | echo             #next line as output
echo "Name" | xargs echo       # this will output Name
```

So you can do it by following expression :-

```
adb shell pm path com.test.example | xargs cut -c 9- | xargs adb pull -
```

For more information you can follow this [link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/12/xargs-examples/).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to [distinguish between standard input and parameters](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput). Not every command understands `-` as referring to standard input, and even those that do usually treat it differently from parameters.

What you probably want is this:

```
adb pull "$(adb shell pm path com.test.example | cut -c 9-)"
```

Comment: You should use something else for `cut`, for when the directory is changed into /data/app2.